# Label doesn't display "_" character

Tags: .net, wpf, label

My `Label.Content` in WPF doesn't  display the first occurrence  of "_" character. Why?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="148" Width="211">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="L_abel" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,31,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

When set `Label.Content ="L__abel"` :

[image]

There is no additional code in project.

Comment: @H.B. - Not a helpful comment.  If one can not ask about anything that is within MSDN documentation, there would be very few questions on stack overflow.  If you don't have an answer, don't post, that simple.

Comment: I disagree.  I don't read the entire documentation as it is a very bulky and not all relevant.  I can find relevant information I need by looking at stack overflow.  I am glad this post is here and glad the answer is as well.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`_` is used in WPF to signal an access key, i.e. a key you can press with <kbd>Alt</kbd> to give focus or invoke an UI element. This is similar to how `&` is used in the Windows API and Windows Forms. Since labels are intended to be used as the label for another control (to describe a text box, for example), this is pretty much expected. You should see the `a` in your example underlined when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611056.aspx):

> To set the access key, add an underscore before the character that should be the access key. If your content has multiple underscore characters, only the first one is converted into an access key; the other underscores appear as normal text. If the underscore that you want converted to the access key is not the first underscore, use two consecutive underscores for any underscores that precede the one that you want to convert. For example, the following code contains an access key and displays as _HelloWorld:
>
> ```
> <Label>__Hello_World</Label>
> ```
>
> Because the underscore that precedes H is a double, the W key registers as the access key.

I guess if you neither require nor want the features `Label` provides, you may use a `TextBlock`.

Comment: So, how to dynamically display content which contains "_"?

Comment: Don't put it in a control that has other uses besides just displaying text. Or escape meta-characters.

Comment: This is mind boggling. Underscore was really the most obscure character they could think of?

And swapping out labels with TextBlocks is awful, since for some godforsaken reason Textblocks don't inherit from Control, meaning you need different styles and bindings for everything.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest method to fix it would be:

Change

```
<Label Content="L_abel" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,31,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

to

```
<Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,31,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<TextBlock Text="L_abel"/>
</Label>
```

Comment: Great solution, works like a Charm. I could not just switch to a Textblock because of ContentStringFormat was needed, but this really fixed it in a whole. Many kudos!

Answer (score 11):

Joey is right! Use

```
<TextBlock>L_abel</TextBlock>
```

and all your underscores will be displayed!

Answer (score 9):

In WPF there is an attribute called **RecognizesAccessKey**, try to change it to false. If you use RadioButton be aware that there is also label behind, and in the RadioButton template to disable access key recognition you must set `RecognizesAccessKey="False"` on template `ContentPresenter`. Then this is disabled, or label is replaced with something else I don't remember now.

Answer (score 4):

Because the _ letter is used for shortcuts (is an accelerator)

Answer (score 1):

I have several places where text bound into a Label control has to display the '_' character. So I wrote a converter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Converters
{
    public class TextToLabelConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value is string strValue)
                ? strValue.Replace("_", "__")
                : Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in the XAML thusly:

```
...
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Converters"
...

<Window.Resources>
    <converters:TextToLabelConverter x:Key="TextToLabelConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding SourceText, Converter={StaticResource TextToLabelConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of TextBlock to solve this issue comes with some disadvantages, such as the inability to center the content vertically (save for placing it within a grid, and there are many situations where the requisite additional controls may be undesirable). In my case, I created a TextBox that behaves like a Label using the following code:

```
var fauxLabel = new TextBox();
fauxLabel.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow; // Avoid the IBeam mouse cursor when hovering
fauxLabel.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
fauxLabel.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
fauxLabel.Focusable = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the documentation and trying several of the solutions here I borrowed from the @BrightShadow and came up with this solution.  What I liked about it is it turned off the hot key/accessor only for the label where I wanted it to.  *This is excerpted from a project that displays properties of scripts and SQL queries.*

```
<Label x:Name="lblParmName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,2,0" Content="@End_Date">
       <Label.Template>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                  <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="False" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </ControlTemplate>
       </Label.Template>
</Label>
```

I could have gone farther and bound the alignment properties to the parent but I wanted to show the easy way to retain the properties of the Label control and still be able to show text with an "underscore".  Hope this helps someone.